# how to get flv frame rate in as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv

Well, i have to set the stage frame rate according to the frame rate of the flv and I will have differnet flv with different frame rate so i have to get frame rate of FlV using action script ??

Is there any method available in Video Class of ActionScript??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also get the FPS from the `NetStream` like so:

`var fps = ns.currentFPS;`

Comment: this is the correct method when using the Video Class rather than the FLV Component

Answer (score 2):

flv.video.FLVPlayback.metadata["framerate"]